# Is there a way to 'paint' or 'fill' tiles in manyland?

Tags: manyland

Is there a way of 'painting' or 'filling' tiles? I'm filling in a large area of background tiles, and it's very laborious clicking and dragging every single one. Is there a fast way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can quick-fill areas in most locations, and at most ranks. To do so, find an empty space and and place tiles in the following order:

```
1    2
4    3
```

or

```
2    1
3    4
```

That is, only the 4 edges, in clockwise or counter-clockwise order starting at the top. This will work with many block types (like solid, back, liquid). A video of this in action can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlvDDsm3dpQ#t=136).